# R Markdown Math Equation Alignment

Tags: r, latex, markdown, tex

I am writing a bunch of math equations in R Markdown inside Rstudio. And I want to align the content either to the left or center. However, seems like the `align` will align them to the right as default.

[image]

I did some google and [some](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56031/left-justify-text-in-latex) of them told me to use a package called `ragged2e`, but it did not work when I added it in. I am wondering if this should be a latex question or rmarkdown question.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're going for here, but line breaks, `\\` go at the end of the line, not the beginning, and the aligmnent operator is `&`. So this:

```
$$
\begin{aligned}
 AR(p): Y_i &= c + \epsilon_i + \phi_i Y_{i-1} \dots \\
 Y_{i} &= c + \phi_i Y_{i-1} \dots
\end{aligned}
$$
```

Produces this:

[image]

Comment: And  how do I then left align the entire block on the page?

Answer (score 12):

left align the formula

```
$\begin{aligned}
AR(p): Y_i &= c + \epsilon_i + \phi_i Y_{i-1} \dots \\
Y_{i} &= c + \phi_i Y_{i-1} \dots
\end{aligned}$
```

&...& show in the line ; $$...$$ display out;

Answer (score 2):

Wow. That works great! Thank you for the help! This worked perfectly in R Studio Markdown.
My code was in an ordered list and is as follows:

```
$\begin{aligned}
    \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{2x-5}{4x^4}=0\\
    \end{aligned}$    

$\begin{aligned}
    \frac{d}{dx}\left( \int_{0}^{x}f(u)\,du\right)=f(x)\\
    \end{aligned}$
```

Comment: This does not work in github. Any ideas why? It does in vscode...