# Markdown equations alignment

Tags: latex, markdown

I am writing equations in wikidocs using markdown and latex.
I tried to align the equations along the equal sign but I can't find the solution. The following is the latex that I wrote currently.

```
$$\begin{align}
Then,\ (x+z)+t & = x+(z+t)\ (\because Rule2) \\
& = x+0_V \\
& = x\ (\because Rule3) \\
\end{align}$$
```

The following is the resulted equation on the wikidocs.
[image]
I found this link
[R Markdown Math Equation Alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27081054/r-markdown-math-equation-alignment), but I still don't know what the problem is. Could you help me please?

Comment: What is wikidocs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran your code on my system and it aligns just fine. [image] Make sure you have the latest version of tools and packages installed. A minimal working example would be useful too.

Comment: Plain text in math mode has to be put in `\text{…}` if available (`amsmath`) or at least wrapped into an `\mbox{…}`. Otherwise you end up in text rendered as math variables, i.e. in italics (as you can see in the demo renderings). That is not good practice.

Answer (score 7):

As `$$...$$` establishes an `equation` math mode environment, as does `\begin{align}`, it is not possible to use the `align` environment inside `$$...$$`; it can only be used (in real LaTeX source, that is) *outside* math mode, because it wants to switch to math mode all by itself.

You should use `\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}` — note ist's *align**ed***, not *align* —, as that is an environment meant to be used *inside* math mode. As such it is suited for use inside the `$$...$$` fencing.

Comment: this works in joplin as well

Comment: It works in vscode, however not in github. Any ideas how to make it work in github as well?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to use

```
$$
\begin{align} 
2x - 5y &=  8 \\ 
3x + 9y &=  -12
\end{align}
$$
```

where each line has a number for the corresponding equation, we can also use

```
$$
\begin{align*} 
2x - 5y &=  8 \\ 
3x + 9y &=  -12
\end{align*}
$$
```

where no equation number at the end of each line